# Change color of a QWidget button based on QDialog choices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I created a GUI that has buttons. When you click the buttons, a QDialog box opens and prompts you to open or close. When the user chooses one of those options, I need the buttons defined in QWidget to change colors. I know how to change the color on the initial click, but I need it predicated off of the QDialog box choice.

This is the Button:

```
self.brkr1_A = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
self.brkr1_A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 70, 40, 40))
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
self.brkr1_A.setFont(font)
self.brkr1_A.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
self.brkr1_A.setObjectName("brkr1_A")
############ Button Event ##############
self.brkr1_A.clicked.connect(self.clickA1)
########################################
```

This is the what the button event calls, located in MainWindow:

```
def clickA1(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'dialogA1'):
        self.dialogA1= WindowA1(self)
    self.dialogA1.show()
    print("A1 Clicked")
```

This is the QDialog that prompts the user to open or close:

```
class WindowA1(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.label = QLabel("Ace 1", self)
        self.label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.button = QPushButton("Open", self)
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Close", self)
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button2, 1, 1)    
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        self.setWindowTitle("Power Lab 4.0")
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()
        ################# Button Events #################
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.OpenBreakerA1)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.CloseBreakerA1)
        ######################################################
        # OpenBreaker is where you will communicate with arduino
    def OpenBreakerA1(self):
        print('Opening A1')
    def CloseBreakerA1(self):
        print('Closing A1')
```

This is what the GUI looks like, you guys would hate me if I attached all the code: 
[brkr1_A is breaker 1 on Ace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9pux.png)

Comment: **When I attempt to use the following:  self.brkr1_A.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;") in OpenBreakerA1 it tells me there is no attribute 'brkr1_A .. How do I go about fixing this?**

Comment: what is brkr1_A? Please show the complete MainWindow code.

Comment: I attached a picture. The GUI is rather large and I don't want to attach 2000+ lines of code. brkr1_A is just a button.

Comment: Try my solution, if I help you do not forget to mark it as correct. If you do not know how to do it, check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Also, if you want us to help you in the future, you must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That minimum example does not necessarily have to be your code, but a code that you create and reproduce the error.

Comment: Do not forget to mark my answer as correct